# $Ex(f)$ has codimension at least 2

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, flips-flops

The following is a part of proof of lemma 6.2 in [the book](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/geometry-and-topology/birational-geometry-algebraic-varieties?format=PB).

$f:X \to Y$ a projective birational morphism of normal varieties

$D$: Weil divisor on $Y$, $E$: exceptional divisor of $f$

$\mathcal{O}_X(1)$: very ample

We get an injection

> $a:\mathcal{O}_Y(mD)=f_*(\mathcal{O}_X(m))\subsetneq f_*(\mathcal{O}_X(m)(E))$ for $m\gg 0$.

Why is this a contradiction if $\mathcal{O}_Y(mD)$ is reflexive and $a$ is an isomorphism outside the codimension $2$ set $f(Ex(f))$?

Answer (score 3):

> > **Lemma** Let $\alpha: \mathscr F\hookrightarrow \mathscr G$ be an injection of $\mathscr O_Y$-modules such that
> >
> > - $Y$ is normal,
> > - $\alpha$ is an isomorphism in codimension $1$,
> > - $\mathscr F$ is reflexive, and
> > - $\mathscr G$ is torsion-free.
> >
> > Then $\alpha$ is an isomorphism.

**Proof:** Since $\mathscr G$ is torsion-free, it embeds into its reflexive hull: $\mathscr G\hookrightarrow \mathscr G^{**}$. Since $Y$ is normal, a reflexive sheaf is determined by its restriction to any big open set (i.e., one with a codimension $2$ complement). This and the rest of the conditions imply that the composition $\mathscr F\hookrightarrow \mathscr G\hookrightarrow \mathscr G^{**}$ is an isomorphism, but then so is $\alpha$. $\square$

**Note** Actually, somewhat less than $Y$ being normal is enough...